# jquery mobile web app startup problem

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

Is there a way to get a web app launched from a home screen icon on the iphone to return to the start div each time it is launched - my problem is that when I close the web app and then open it again using the home screen icon it returns to the last 'page' I had open while it loads - it then goes back to the first 'page' once loading is complete. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. For reference:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="startup-graphic.png" />
```

This `head` tag only seems to work if the png is sized 320x460 pixels. This makes sense but was not immediately obvious to me.